# Significance of Confidence Interval & Mean +- Standard Deviation

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

[image: Kindly read instructions from Image FIRST]

**For the image uploaded with data, I have following queries:**

1. What is the significance of finding CI Interval, when we already know that we are 95.45% sure about Population Mean will lie in range of (34.6 & 38.6)?
2. My Question Is, Should Confidence Interval Values (36.40 & 36.79) should have been equal to Range of shaded portion (i.e. 38.6 & 34.6) ???

Comment: The shaded region in your figure includes more like 68% of the total area under the curve than 95%. A confidence interval will use the standard deviation of the estimate $\bar X$ rather than the estimated standard deviation of the population. // See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

A 95% confidence interval for the population mean $\mu,$ based on a *normal* sample of size $n = 100$ with $\bar X = 36.6, S = 2.0,$ would be
of the form $\bar X \pm t^* S/\sqrt{n},$ where $t^*$ cuts probability $0.025 =2.5\%$ from the upper tail of
Student's t distribution with 99 degrees of freedom.

From printed tables of t distributions or from software
(R output below) $t^* = 1.984.$ [Some texts might use approximations, either using the value $1.96$ that cuts probability $0.025$ from the upper tail of a standard normal distribution, or for simplicity just $2.0.]$

```
qt(.975, 99)
1.984217
```

Roughly speaking, the desired CI is about $36.6\pm 0.4$ or $(36.2, 37.0).$ Please follow the convention in your textbook, if you need more places of accuracy.

*Note:* Your figure and the work you have shown in your Question suggests you may be using a "confidence interval" (CI) of
the form $\bar X \pm S$ or $\bar X \pm S/\sqrt{n}.$

- From a statistical point of view, the first of these
  variants makes no sense as a CI---its widespread use in some
  biological and social sciences (to make 'error bars') notwithstanding.
- The second of these is approximately a 68% confidence interval.